# JMeter Aggreagate Graph long labels

Tags: graph, jmeter

I have a little bit long names (20-30 characters) for HTTP endpoints and I can't see full name in Aggregate Graph. How can I fix it?

Oleg

Comment: did you try to change "Max length of x-axis label" to value above 30, e.g. 35?

Comment: It works. UI a little bit confused me because it don't have default value and I didn't try.